# How to make bootstrap 4 d-flex <table> cells equal height?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, bootstrap-4

**Context**

I am using `<table>` element with bootstrap 4 `d-flex` to render a table. The cells (`<td>`) has different content within one row (`<tr>`), and unfortunately this results different cell heights

**Question**

How to make cells height equal? (bordering is only for visual diagnostics)

Current rendered output:

[image]

Current html:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
  <thead>
     <tr class="d-flex">
        <!-- columns omitted for the sake of clarity, total of x in col-x == 12 -->
        <th class="col-2">Totals</th>
        <th class="col-1">Score</th>
        <th class="col-1">Status</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <!-- columns omitted for the sake of clarity, total of x in col-x == 12 -->
        <td class="col-2">
           <button data-pickstate="0" data-pickid="2619-O-TOTAL" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect waves-light btn-block btn-sm">
           O 198.5 (-110)
           </button>
        </td>
        <td class="col-1">107</td>
        <td class="col-1">OVER</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <!-- columns omitted for the sake of clarity, total of x in col-x == 12 -->
        <td class="col-2">
           <button data-pickstate="0" data-pickid="2619-E-TOTAL" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect waves-light btn-block btn-sm">
           U 198.5 (-110)
           </button>
        </td>
        <td class="col-1">98</td>
        <td class="col-1"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <td class="col-12">free text here</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables do not work well with flexbox. They are fundamentally incompatible.